# Allegro 5 C/C++: Problema com cores

Tags: c, c++, allegro

Estou utilizando o allegro 5, e li que para criar cores é só usar `al_map_rgb` ou `al_color_html`, então eu fiz um map para acessar facilmente várias cores:

```
#include "allegro5\allegro.h"
#include "allegro5\allegro_color.h"

int main()
{
    al_init();

    map<string, ALLEGRO_COLOR> color;
    color["black"] = al_color_html("#000000");
    color["gray"] = al_color_html("#808080");
    color["silver"] = al_color_html("#c0c0c0");
    color["white"] = al_color_html("#ffffff");
    color["maroon"] = al_color_html("#800000");
    color["red"] = al_color_html("#ff0000");
    color["olive"] = al_color_html("#808000");
    color["yellow"] = al_color_html("#ffff00");
    color["green"] = al_color_html("#008000");
    color["lime"] = al_color_html("#00ff00");
    color["teal"] = al_color_html("#008080");
    color["aqua"] = al_color_html("#00ffff");
    color["naavi"] = al_color_html("#0000ff");
    color["blue"] = al_color_html("#000080");
    color["purple"] = al_color_html("#800080");
    color["fuchsia"] = al_color_html("#ff00ff");

    return 0;
}
```

Mas o programa crasha quando eu testo. Então, fazendo testes, descobri que se eu utilizar apenas 6 cores, meu programa executa perfeitamente:

```
#include "allegro5\allegro.h"
#include "allegro5\allegro_color.h"

int main()
{
    al_init();

    map<string, ALLEGRO_COLOR> color;
    color["black"] = al_color_html("#000000");
    color["gray"] = al_color_html("#808080");
    color["silver"] = al_color_html("#c0c0c0");
    color["white"] = al_color_html("#ffffff");
    color["maroon"] = al_color_html("#800000");
    color["red"] = al_color_html("#ff0000");

    return 0;
}
```

Mas se eu adiciono mais uma cor qualquer ele volta a crashar:

```
#include "allegro5\allegro.h"
#include "allegro5\allegro_color.h"

int main()
{
    al_init();

    map<string, ALLEGRO_COLOR> color;
    color["black"] = al_color_html("#000000");
    color["gray"] = al_color_html("#808080");
    color["silver"] = al_color_html("#c0c0c0");
    color["white"] = al_color_html("#ffffff");
    color["maroon"] = al_color_html("#800000");
    color["red"] = al_color_html("#ff0000");
    color["blue"] = al_color_html("#000080");

    return 0;
}
```

Da mesma forma, se eu usar um for para gerar cores, sem salvar em variável nenhuma, depois da sétima repetição o programa crasha.

Isso funciona:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    al_color_html("#000080");
}
```

Isso não:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    al_color_html("#000080");
}
```

Porém, se faço isso:

```
for (int i = 1; true; i++)
{
    cout << i << " ";
    al_color_html("#000080");
}
```

Tenho como saída `1 2 3 4 5 ... 57 58 59`, e se faço isso:

```
for (int i = 1; true; i++)
{
    al_color_html("#000080");
    cout << i << " ";
}
```

Tenho como saída `1 2 3 4 5 ... 15 16 17`

**Nota:** o erro também ocorre com o `al_map_rgb`, porém consigo executar o comando mais vezes

Comment: Também ocorre se você usar `std::map::insert()` em vez do `std::map::operator[]()`?  Isso tem cara de ser problema com o `allocator`, mas talvez seja problema do `operator[]`.

Comment: De todo modo, se você só quer acessar as cores rapida e convenientemente, é melhor usar um `enum` como chave e, como você não deve adicionar cores dinamicamente, usar um _array_ estático com tantas posições quanto há membros no `enum`.

Comment: @Wtrmute, o erro não está no map,se eu uso um for e apenas gerar cores, depois da sétima o programa crasha

Comment: Ele quebra e não te diz nada? Você consegue pôr o `for` dentro de um `try ... catch (std::exception & ex) { cout << ex.what() << endl; } catch (std::string & str) { cout << "Peguei string " << str << endl; }`?

Comment: @Wtrmute, não funciona, não recebo mensagem de erro ou nada do tipo, o programa simplesmente crasha. Atualizei o post

Answer (score 0):

A resposta é bem simples: atualizar o [Allegro](https://www.allegro.cc/files/) e o [MinGW](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/).

Comment: Por favor lembre-se de aceitar sua própria resposta, assim que possível... :)